# SQL: retrieve all rows that have a date between two dates

Tags: mysql

I'm making a small booking manager for my family's bed and breakfast.

I have a "booking" table that contains among other things a column called "arrivalDate" and a column called "departureDate".

I want to do a SELECT query where I retrieve all bookings that cover a certain date.

IE:

booking table:

```
name= John, arrivalDate= 01/01/2014, departureDate= 10/01/2014
name= Susie, arrivalDate= 04/01/2014, departureDate= 07/01/2014
```

I would like to do a query where it returns all bookings that are staying on 05/01/2014
In this case it would return both John's and Susie's booking.

Another query for 02/01/2014 would return only John's booking.

What would such an SQL query look like?

(NOTE: to not confuse anyone, the dates I put here are d/m/Y, I know that SQL uses Y/m/d, I can sort that myself, just looking for the logic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from table where arrivalDate <= yourDate and yourDate <= departureDate
```

Replace `yourDate` with date which you need (for example `05/01/2014` according to DB format).

Comment: `select * from table where yourDate between arrivalDate and departureDate`

Comment: Thank you, they both work. It might seem funny but I actually realized my error was coming from a lack of encapsulating quotes in my query in my PHP code. But thank you for your swift answers!